# Using java web3j to create wallet but how then connect to private running blockchain?

Tags: java, blockchain, ethereum, geth, web3-java

I'm using the java web3j lib and creating a new wallet file using:

```
WalletUtils.generateFullNewWalletFile()
```

With:

```
Web3j web3 = Web3j.build(new HttpService());
```

... I'm connecting to my local private blockchain running geth.

The question is. How can I add some test either to my wallet and what is the context between my local created wallet and the geth client I'm running.

How can I connect the web3j created wallet with to the geth client?

With:

```
WalletUtils.loadCredentials()
```

.. I am able the get the wallets public address but the account is not listed in the geth client when I am using:

```
web3.ethAccounts().send().getAccounts()
```

How this fits together?

Answer (score 0):

Initial ether needs to be specified in `genesis.json` when you initialize your private blockchain.

A simple example:

```
{
    "config": {
        "chainId": 29462
    },
    "difficulty": "0x400",
    "gasLimit": "0x8000000",
    "alloc": {
        "d69cc234de15189f0ba998a41421961e89837fc5": {
            "balance": "30000000000000000000000000000"
        }
    }
}
```

The address specified here needs to be created before initializing the genesis block. You can create the address manually using `geth`, or you can use the one you created with `WalletUtils.generateFullNewWalletFile()`. The important part here is to make sure to use the same keystore directory when running your `geth` commands. Whatever `destinationDirectory` you passed into `generateFullNewWalletFile()` needs to be passed into `geth` with the `--keystore` option.

If you've already created your private blockchain and allocated ether to a different account than the one you created in web3j, make sure you're using the same keystore directory for both accounts (and the directory matches the `--keystore` option) and simply transfer the ether from your original account to the new one you created.

Comment: Thx for explanation :)